# Setting an existing column to auto-increment

Tags: sql, sql-server

HI I have an existing table witch has a column ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId.This column is set as a primary key and has around 60000 rows of data.

The type of the column is int and it has a unique id for each row.The rows were transfered from another table , from another db and we needed to preserve the exact id values in the new table.

This is what I did so far:

```
CREATE TABLE ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments(
ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId int NOT NULL,
RootStorageId int NOT NULL,
StorageFileName varchar(200),
OriginalFileName varchar(200),
Title varchar(200),
Deletion_Date datetime,
Creation_Date datetime,
Modification_Date datetime,
RowVersion int,
CreatedBy int,
ModifiedBy int,
DeletedBy int,
CONSTRAINT FK_ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments_FileShareRootStorage 
FOREIGN KEY (RootStorageId) REFERENCES FileShareRootStorage(FileShareRootStorageId)
```

)

After that I have runed this script in order to add the data to the new table:

```
 INSERT INTO [LocalServerB].[dbo].[ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments] (ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId , RootStorageId , StorageFileName , OriginalFileName , Title , Deletion_Date , Creation_Date , Modification_Date , [RowVersion] , CreatedBy , ModifiedBy , DeletedBy)
SELECT d.DocumentId     as ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId,
       2                as RootStorageId,
       d.RealName       as StorageFileName,
       d.FileName       as OriginalFileName,
       d.Title          as Title,
       d.Deletion_Date  as Deletion_Date,
       d.Creation_Date  as Creation_Date,
       d.Modification_Date as Modification_Date,
       d.[RowVersion]          as [RowVersion],
       d.CreatedBy             as CreatedBy,
       d.ModifiedBy            as ModifiedBy,
       d.DeletedBy             as DeletedBy
FROM [LocalServerA].[dbo].[Sync_Exams] as e 
JOIN [LocalServerA].[dbo].[Documents]  as d ON d.DocumentId = e.QuestionsDocumentID OR
                                     d.DocumentID = e.AnswersDocumentID
```

So far so good now I have to set the ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId as the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId)
GO
```

Now as the last part I need to set the column to auto-increment every time I add a new row.
This is preety easy with SSMS but I will need the script to run it on are actual DB.

All the solution I find online say that this is not posible , that the column will be regenarated , but there must be a way to be able to set it as an IDENTITY AUTO INCREMENT without the column to be regenerated.

I have tryed doing it with SSMS and nothing get's regenerated even after I add some new rows.The interesting this is that it continues incrementig from the the highest Id it finds.

Does anyone know how to set a column as an AUTO INCREMENT Identity?

Comment: When you change it through SSMS, you have the option of generating a script rather than executing the command. You need to click the generate change script button. For this to work you need to have gone to Tools / Options / Designers / Table and Database Designers and unchecked "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation". The script generated will create a new table with the identity and set identity_insert on then insert into that table, turn identity_insert off then drop original table and rename.

Comment: It is not possible to change a column to an Identity column after creation or remove the identity specification after the column has been created.  Instead, you can add an Identity column to an existing table or create a new table with an identity column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to be an identity when you create the table then use

```
 set Identity_Insert ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments on
```

before inserting your data, then

```
 set Identity_Insert ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments off
```

afterwards. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments(
    ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId int NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    RootStorageID int,
    ...
)

set identity_insert ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments on

insert ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments(ExamQuestionsAnswersDocumentId, RootStorageID, ...) 
Select ...

set identity_insert ExamQuestionsAnswersDocuments off
```